# Fresh Apache2 installation on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, apache2

I uninstalled a corrupted Apache2 on Ubuntu and when I re/install Apache2 it will restore the same files as the old one.

I want to do a fresh installation of apache2.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is not enough to use `sudo apt-get uninstall`, that will keep the configuration.
For a complete uninstall, use `sudo apt-get purge apache2`.

You may also be interested in reading [this Q&A on the Ubuntu Stack Exchange site](https://askubuntu.com/q/176964/254326), which covers the same problem.

Comment: after uninstalltion i get same file as old can u help me

Comment: So, you're getting the same problems even after using `purge`? Then take a look at that link. Especially the top answer, by user Oli.